# How to load multiple sheets from single idw file on Autodesk forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-designautomation

Currently I'm working on Autodesk IDA I have zip file in bucket which contains few IDW files.
In which 1 IDW file contains 3 sheets, now I want to load drawing sheet with all 3 sheets on viewer. As of now I'm able to load only one sheet on viewer other 2 is not loading.

IDW file structure
Sampledrawingsheet.idw
-sheet 1
-sheet 2
-sheet 3

Please guide us to load all the sheets on viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi we can solve this problem by using document browser in our JavaScript code.
we have to add extension for that(Document Browser )
e.g.
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.DocumentBrowser').

This solution is now working in my code.
Thank You

Comment: This might be useful too: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/switch-between-sheets